# Why is debug used as dependency and not devDependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have seen that a lot of node modules/frameworks ([express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express), [sockets.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser), [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)) that use [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) as dependency rather than as devDependency, while clearly debug is a module for debugging node application in development (unless someone would like to debug in production ¯_(ツ)_/¯).

Is there any particular reason to do so?

Comment: Any package that required/imported into your code would need to be a dependency, this is because that piece of code required on the fact that "debug" is installed as a dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't guess why developer makes especially this choice, but in the packages you mention, *debug* module is more used as a fancy `console.log` than a debugging tool.

It is used to log some information while the application is running. Ex. in *[express](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/application.js#L87)*:

```
debug('booting in %s mode', env);
```

Debugging application is not the same than developping it. All these packages are extensively tested and `devDependency` stands for tools when the program is developed, not when you debug it for your use case. Ex. in *[socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/e5f0ceaee060306c38c7a5abf470f693b609a17d/Readme.md#debug--logging)*, you can ask for the full log if you are in an developpement environment:

```
DEBUG=socket.io* node myapp
```

So it makes sense to add it as a `dependency` and not as a `devDependency`.